# Slide a div offscreen using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is a bit of a challenge. Here's what I'm looking for:

1. 3 divs on screen
2. Div 1 resides in the middle of the page (centered)
3. Div 2 resides just off the screen on the far left
4. Div 3 resides just off the screen on the far right
5. `OnClick`, Div 1 slides to the position Div 2 was (to the left), Div 2 slides off the screen entirely, Div 3 slides to where Div 3 was (middle, centered). A new div arrives on the right.

I've tried using jQuery animation and AddClass. jQuery doesn't like sliding a div offscreen.

Any thoughts?

For an example of what I'm describing, visit [Groupon.com](http://www.groupon.com/). I thought it was a cool idea, and have given myself the challenge of recreating it. So far, no dice.

-D

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: "jQuery doesn't like sliding a div offscreen" ...You just have to animate an element (i.e. abs positioned) to a negative left offset..(example here -> http://jsfiddle.net/steweb/tUU7a/)

Comment: Show what you have so far and we will help through the parts that are not working as planned.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/ykbgT/embedded/result/

http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/ykbgT/

This is the basic functionality.  It doesn't scale to more divs, etc, but that should get you started.

The key is to wrap your elements in a container and make the overflow hidden.

**Update**:

Here's a slightly better version that handles any number of divs (greater than 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/ykbgT/1/

**Simplified further**:

http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/ykbgT/2/

**Code snippet**:

```js
$('.box').click(function() {

    $(this).animate({
        left: '-50%'
    }, 500, function() {
        $(this).css('left', '150%');
        $(this).appendTo('#container');
    });

    $(this).next().animate({
        left: '50%'
    }, 500);
});
```

```css
body {
    padding: 0px;    
}

#container {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;  
}

.box {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
    height: 300px;
    line-height: 300px;
    font-size: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 2px solid black;
    left: 150%;
    top: 100px;
    margin-left: -25%;
}

#box1 {
    background-color: green;
    left: 50%;
}

#box2 {
    background-color: yellow;
}

#box3 {
    background-color: red;
}

#box4 {
    background-color: orange;
}

#box5 {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    
    <div id="box1" class="box">Div #1</div>
    <div id="box2" class="box">Div #2</div>
    <div id="box3" class="box">Div #3</div>
    <div id="box4" class="box">Div #4</div>
    <div id="box5" class="box">Div #5</div>
    
</div>
```

Comment: +1 for a good solid demo and beating me to it. ;-) (and for using % instead of me working with pixels :swearing:)

Comment: Agreed. I worked on this for about 3 hours and got nowhere near this. Thanks a ton! It's a work of art :)

Comment: Okay sry that took forever. I couldn't figure out how to accept it ;) Thanks again!

Comment: Wow.  Got a down vote exactly one year later.  I wish people would comment why they down voted sometimes.

Comment: I would just like to add that this technique (using percentage animation) breaks in IE8 with jQuery 1.7.2. I've fallen back to $("body").width()+"px" instead, which seems to work.

Comment: @Jeff B is there a possibility that you can look at my [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13126909/change-multiple-element-contents-background-depending-on-slider-contents) please. Its very similar to this one, the only difference is that I have both left and right arrows, to go back and forth.

Comment: Thanks Jeff that's what i was looking for a long time

Answer (score 3):

Maybe I misinterpreted. I though you wanted three divs in a row, and only the ones on the end sliding and whatnot.

http://jsfiddle.net/acsfy/

(I know you're using jQuery for this, but it pissed me off as I was trying to force it to work. You'd have to adapt this for your purposes.)

Comment: I used to feel the same way about jQuery.  Then one day it clicked and I haven't looked back.  Goodbye `document.getElementById()`!

Comment: @Jeff I think I'm just on the cusp of that switch. The other day, I was working on this complicated navigation thing - grabbing links, changing styles, effects, etc. The deadline loomed, so I just said, "Screw it," and switched to jQuery. It took me ten minutes and 20 lines - 20 lines! - to do the whole thing. It might not have "clicked," but it's only a matter of time.

Answer (score 1):

Extending **Jeff B** answer, i've included [Hammer.js](http://hammerjs.github.io/) and made a circular list.

```
$(function() {
$("#esq").click(function() {
    console.log("Esquerda !");
    var obj = $(".ativo");
    $(obj).animate({
        left: '-50%'
    }, 500, function() {
        $(this).css('left', '+150%');
        $(this).appendTo('#container');
    });
    $(obj).next().animate({
        left: '+50%'
    }, 500, function() {
        $(this).addClass('ativo');
        $(obj).removeClass('ativo');
    });
});

$("#dir").click(function() {
    console.log("Direita !");
    var obj = $(".ativo");
    var prox = $(obj).siblings(":last");
    $(obj).animate({
        left: '+150%'
    }, 500, function() {
        $(prox).prependTo('#container');
    });
    $(prox).css('left', '-50%');
    $(prox).animate({
        left: '+50%'
    }, 500, function() {
        $(this).addClass('ativo');
        $(obj).removeClass('ativo');
    });
});

var hammertime = new Hammer(document.getElementById("container"));
hammertime.get('swipe').set({direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_HORIZONTAL});
hammertime.on('swipeleft', function() {
    $("#esq").trigger("click");
});
hammertime.on('swiperight', function() {
    $("#dir").trigger("click");
});
```

});

Example in: http://jsfiddle.net/tvLt1r9h/2/

Answer (score 0):

And... not a year too late. If you want it to start on the first div, your css needs to look like this.

```
    #box1 { background-color:#333; }
    #box2 { background-color:#333; left: -50%; }
    #box3 { background-color:#333; left: 150%; }
    #box4 { background-color:#333; left: 150%; }
    #box5 { background-color:#333; left: 150%; }
```