# jQuery animate divs on/off screen sequentially with navigation arrows

Tags: jquery, html, screen, slide, arrows

What i want to do is to slide divs off and on screen sequentially by clicking on navigation arrows left and right according to the direction. When you click the right arrow divs slide on screen from right to left and it works fine. I can't figure out the code for the left arrow so the divs will slide on screen from the opposite direction left to right. Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ykbgT/6696/

There is another question [Slide divs off screen using jQuery + added navigation arrows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13016392/slide-divs-off-screen-using-jquery-added-navigation-arrows) marked as answered but the answer does not give any details for the functions of the navigation arrows.

Here is the code:

HTML

```
<div class="move left">&larr;</div>
<div class="move right">&rarr;</div>

<div id="container">

<div id="box1" class="box current">Div #1</div>
<div id="box2" class="box">Div #2</div>
<div id="box3" class="box">Div #3</div>
<div id="box4" class="box">Div #4</div>
<div id="box5" class="box">Div #5</div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
    padding: 0px;    
}

#container {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;  
}

.box {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
    height: 300px;
    line-height: 300px;
    font-size: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 2px solid black;
    left: 150%;
    top: 100px;
    margin-left: -25%;
}

#box1 {
    background-color: green;
    left: 50%;
}

#box2 {
    background-color: yellow;
}

#box3 {
    background-color: red;
}

#box4 {
    background-color: orange;
}

#box5 {
    background-color: blue;
}
.move{
    position:fixed;
    z-index:2;
    top:50%;
    margin-top:-20px;
    text-align:center;
    padding:20px;
    background:#fff;
    color: #000;
}
.left{
    left:0;
}
.right{
    right:0;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$('.right').click(function(event) {
$('.current').animate({
    left: '-50%'
}, 500, function() {
    $(this).css('left', '150%');
    $(this).appendTo('#container');
    $(this).removeClass('current');
});

$('.current').next().animate({
    left: '50%'
}, 500, function (){
 $(this).addClass('current');
});


});

$('.left').click(function(event) {
$('.current').animate({
    left: '50%'
}, 500, function() {
    $(this).css('left', '-150%');
    $(this).prependTo('#container');
    $(this).removeClass('current');
});

$('.current').prev().animate({
    left: '-50%'
}, 500, function (){
 $(this).addClass('current');
});


});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsprakash/MABZj/1/)**

Try this

I have edited your code

### code

```
var i = 1;
$('.right').click(function () {
    if (i < $('#container div').length) {
        $("#box" + i).animate({
            left: '-50%'
        }, 400, function () {
            var $this = $("#box" + i);
            $this.css('left', '150%')
                .appendTo($('.container'));
        });
        $("#box" + i).next().animate({
            left: '50%'
        }, 400);
        i++;
    }
});
$('.left').click(function () {

    if (i > 1) {
        $("#box" + i).animate({
            left: '150%'
        }, 400, function () {
            var $this = $("#box" + i);
            $this.css('right', '-150%')
                .appendTo($('.container'));
        });
        $("#box" + i).prev().animate({
            left: '50%'
        }, 400);
        i--;
    }
});
```

Hope this helps,Thank you

Comment: I noticed your code is limited to a given number of boxes (5). Please check my answer below for no limitations to the number of divs!

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUTION WITH LESS JS AND CSS TRANSITIONS**

Help from [@BenjaminGruenbaum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1348195/benjamin-gruenbaum)

Check the working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zPVFd/1/

**HTML - class '.current' removed:**

```
<div id="box1" class="box">Div #1</div>
```

**CSS - added css transitions to '.box'**

```
.box {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 300px;
  line-height: 300px;
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid black;
  left: 150%;
  top: 100px;
  margin-left: -25%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;

}
```

**JS CODE**

```
var boxes = $(".box").get(),
    current = 0;
$('.right').click(function () {
    if (current == (-boxes.length + 1)){
        } else {
        current--;
    updateBoxes();
    }
});

function updateBoxes() {
    for (var i = current; i < (boxes.length + current); i++) {
        boxes[i - current].style.left = (i * 100 + 50) + "%";
    }
}

$('.left').click(function () {
    if (current == 0){
    }else{
    current++;
    updateBoxes();
    }
});
```

Comment: you should try the maximum to maintain the OP code version , OP had tried something , he just want to complete it

Comment: I didnt down vote you , but found you down voted so a +1 from me

Comment: @SarathSprakash Actually it's the same code from the OP version, but with CSS3 transitions instead of animate and a more compact code approach. The result is working fine! Thanks for the +1! I don't get it why i got down voted for a second working answer:)