# Two divs inside another div and slide left right

Tags: css

I have a div that is masked off in terms of its width. Inside, I have 2 divs of the same width floated, so 100% + 100%. This means that either the left is visible or the right is visible at any one time.

In fact, what I'm trying to achieve is almost exactly the same as this:

[jquery slide div within a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15338054/jquery-slide-div-within-a-div)

Just one difference though. The height of my parent isn't fixed, it's dependent on the child size. So when I apply `position: absolute;` to the parent, it all goes pear-shaped.

Any solutions to this? I can use flexbox if necessary as I don't support IE8/9.

CSS would be something like this

```
.outer-wrap {
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    width:300px;
}

.middle-wrap {
    overflow:hidden;
    position:absolute; // this doesn't work because it has no fixed height
    left:0;
    width:600px;
}

.middle-wrap.open {
    right:0;
}

.inner-wrap {
    float:left;
    width:300px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="outer-wrap">
    <div class="middle-wrap">
        <div class="inner-wrap"></div>
        <div class="inner-wrap"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please put a [mcve] in your question

Comment: note: floated elements don't affect the height of their parent elements - the parent remains height 0 if it contains only floated elements and has no fixed height...

Comment: @Johannes - I'm just trying to achieve the above without using absolute positioning.

Comment: The CSS visible attribute should probably be used to toggle the display of the two "inner-wrap" divs instead of using a fixed width containing div and the overflow:hidden attribute to ensure "that either the left is visible or the right is visible at any one time".

Comment: @GottZ OP is saying he *doesn't* support IE8/9, hence he can use flexbox for potential solutions. Either way though, suggesting users avoid supporting certain browsers is not a constructive comment. Developers typically are required by their workplace to support certain browsers.

Comment: @JohnH - thanks for the alterative solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another edit: I created a codepen, it's here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oxwmex CLick on the two buttons on the far right, they switch between the states

As you noted, your solution doesn't work because `.middle-wrap` has no fixed height. Try it with the following settings (note: no floats, no absolute positions):

```
.outer-wrap {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.middle-wrap {
  position: relative;
  width: 600px;
  left: 0px;
}

.inner-wrap {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

This will display the left of the two `.inner-wrap`s within the visible part of `.outer-wrap`. To make the right `.inner-wrap` visible apply something like

```
jQuery(".middle-wrap").css("left", "-300px")
```

to the element or event you use for switching between the two inner-wraps. Or if you want it animated:

```
jQuery(".middle-wrap").aminmate({left: "-300px"})
```

(Plus another method to switch back to `left: 0px`)

The heigth of all elements is automatically adjusted to the heigth of the higher of the two `.inner-wrap` elements.

P.S. (edit): Erase the `style="height:100px;"` settings from the inner-wraps in the HTML, just fill them with some content to see it working.