# Image slider that repeats infinitely without a return

Tags: jquery, slider, banner

We are currently using an image slider for advertising in the homepage.
However, we are experiencing problems with the rotation of images within the slider.
The slider is now moving from right to left, but after loading the last image, the first image is not coming back from right, but from left first image back and then sliding back.
What needs to be modified to implement the slider as if it were still connected to the right?

I used the code below.
[jquery slide div within a div](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15338054/11565221)

[html]

```
<div class="ads">
 <div class="movable">
  <div id="ss1">
   <a href="..." target="_blank"><img src="..."></a>
  </div>
  <div id="ss2">
   <a href="..." target="_blank"><img src="..."></a>
  </div>
  <div id="ss3">
   <a href="..." target="_blank"><img src="..."></a>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

[jquery]

```
$(function() {
$('.ads').each(function() {
    var $gal = $(this),
        $movable = $(".movable", $gal),
        $slides = $(">*", $movable),
        N = $slides.length,
        C = 0,
        itv = null;
    function play() { itv = setInterval(anim, 2000); }
    function stop() { clearInterval(itv); }
    function anim() {
        C = ($(this).is(".prev") ? --C : ++C) < 0 ? N - 1 : C % N;
        $movable.css({ transform: "translateX(-" + (C * 100) + "%)" });
    }
    $(".prev, .next", this).on("click", anim);
    // $gal.hover(stop, play);
    play();
  });
});
```

[css]

```
.ads {
 top: auto;
 right: 2%;
 bottom: 3%;
 position: absolute;
 width: 25vw;
 height: 25vw;
 max-width: 400px;
 max-height: 400px;
 z-index: 11;
}

.ads .slide_img {
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

.slide_img img {
 width: 25vw;
 height: 25vw;
 max-width: 500px;
 max-height: 500px;
}

.ads #nav_slide {
 width: 100%;
 bottom: 12%;
 height: 11px;
 position: absolute;
 text-align: center;
 z-index: 98;
 cursor: default;
}

.slide_img {
 z-index: -1;
}

.xbtn {
 position: relative;
 right: 2%;
 bottom: 99%;
 text-align: right;
 color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}

.xbtn p {
 position: relative;
 line-height: 20px;
}

button:focus {
 outline: none;
}
```

Comment: Did you include the CSS from that answer as well?

Comment: @Bruno Monteiro Thank you. CSS added.

Comment: I don't get what the problem is...I made a "working" example with you code here: https://codepen.io/brunomont/pen/zQLgaj
Everything seems to be working, as far as the slide goes. But the CSS is different from the link you posted, and that's why the images are showing below each other.
As far as the original question, about the slide not working, for me it looks fine...