# Problems with a jquery content slider

Tags: jquery, onclick, slider

Been looking for ages for a slider that changes content on click and this is exactly what I'm trying to do:

[Slide a div offscreen using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4741880/slide-a-div-offscreen-using-jquery)

But for some reason I can't get it to work. I've copied the code from the jsfiddle page but it wont work. I'm probably messing something super basic up but here's my code :)

```
<style>
body {
padding: 0px;    
}

#container {
position: absolute;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
overflow: hidden;  
}

.box {
position: absolute;
width: 50%;
height: 300px;
line-height: 300px;
font-size: 50px;
text-align: center;
border: 2px solid black;
left: 50%;
top: 100px;
margin-left: -25%;
}

#box1 {
background-color: green;
left: -50%;
}

#box2 {
background-color: yellow;
}

#box3 {
background-color: red;
left: 150%;
}

#box4 {
background-color: orange;
left: 150%;
}

#box5 {
background-color: blue;
left: 150%;
}

</style>


<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>

</head>

<body>


<script type="text/javascript">

$('.box').click(function() {
$('.box').each( function() {
    if ($(this).offset().left < 0) {
        $(this).css("left", "150%");
    }
});

$(this).animate({
     left: '-50%'
 }, 500);

 if ($(this).next().size() > 0) {
     $(this).next().animate({
         left: '50%'
     }, 500);
 } else {
     $(this).prevAll().last().animate({
         left: '50%'
     }, 500);
 }
});j


</script>

<div id="container">

<div id="box1" class="box">Div #1</div>
<div id="box2" class="box">Div #2</div>
<div id="box3" class="box">Div #3</div>
<div id="box4" class="box">Div #4</div>
<div id="box5" class="box">Div #5</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to put:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
```

after

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

and

```
});
```

before

```
</script>
```

your jquery version is very old..

Comment: thanks! that fixed it. I also wanna have links inside the div, so is it possible to add next and prev buttons so the div itself doesn't move onclick?

Comment: yes, is possible, but i cannot help you, i could, but ill go to sleep in a few minutes

Comment: It would be a massive help

Comment: check thist tutorial.. it will help you http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/02/slide-elements-in-different-directions

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the javascript on the bottom of the page ( before closing body tag ) to be sure all the DOM is loaded, or to use jQuery ready method

```
$(function(){
   //your code here
});
```

Also, you have one "j" string after your code. And suggestion - upgrade the jQuery version to 1.9.1  http://jsfiddle.net/gZ74f/1/